# d3 obj.exit() is working, but obj.enter() throws error for "the node before is not a child of this node"

Tags: d3.js

I have a parallel coordinates (parallel axes) chart that is 90% working, but I'm having issues with entering new data. I am getting the error, "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node."

I am copying the re-drawing of the axes from when the chart is initialized exactly, so that should be working fine. It seems like it's a problem with my identifier function when adding new data (potentially), although, my exit function works fine with it.

When I console log axes.enter(), the output is correct (correct element being added in correct spot). However, there's the insert error that seems to stop it from rendering.

```
function updateAxis(newFilters, selectedAxis, newData) {

    dimensions = d3.keys(newData[0]).filter(function(d) {
      return d != "PID" &&  d != "Age" && (y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain(d3.extent(data, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
          .range([height, 0]))
    });

    x.domain(dimensions);

    var axes = d3.selectAll(".dimension")
    .data(dimensions, d => d);

    axes
      .transition('update')
      .duration(500)
      .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d])); })
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + x(d) + ")";

    });

    axes.selectAll("text")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

    foreground
      .transition('update')
      .duration(500)
      .attr("d", path);

    background
      .transition('update')
      .duration(500)
      .attr("d", path);


    /********start axis enter() updates*************/

    axes.enter().append("axes")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d])); })
    .append("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("y", -9)
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .style("fill", "black");

    axes.append("axes")
    .attr("class", "dimension")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { console.log ("axes.enter() transform: ", d); return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
    .call(d3.drag()
          .subject(function(d) {
    //console.log(d);
    return {x: x(d)}; })
          .on("start", function(d) {
    dragging[d] = x(d);
    background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
  })
          .on("drag", function(d) {
    dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
    foreground.attr("d", path);
    dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
    x.domain(dimensions);
    axes.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
  })
          .on("end", function(d) {
    delete dragging[d];
    transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
    transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
    background
      .attr("d", path)
      .transition()
      .delay(500)
      .duration(0)
      .attr("visibility", null);
  }));


  // Add and store a brush for each axis.
  axes.append("axes")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .each(function(d) { 
    d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY()
                         .extent([[-10,0], [10,height]])
                         .on("brush", brush)           
                         .on("end", brush)
                        )
  })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("width", 16);

    /********end axis enter() updates*************/

    axes.exit()
      .transition('exit-transition')
      .duration(500)
      .attr("opacity", 0)
      .remove();
  };
```

Expected output is re-drawing the lines and adding in the path data (foreground and background). Foreground and background are added correctly, but the axes are not getting re-drawn correctly. So the foreground/background updates, there is space allocated in the visualization for the axis, all other axes are moved to match the new foreground/background, it's just the enter() axes themselves not being added back in. I suspect it's related to this "insert" error.

Unfortunately I can't share the entire visualization because the data I'm working on is protected, but the newData file is updating correctly and the dimensions re-add the axes in the correct place. Essentially, the axes is being added back in the order it was removed in (so it's being added back "in place" as much as possible).

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong - appreciate all help/advice! Let me know if I need to add more details.

Comment: Can you indicate which line is throwing an error?

Comment: I actually figured out what was wrong with this! I had the wrong appending hierarchy from when i initialized the code. Thank you!